# Qemu gets stuck at booting from hard disk

Tags: linux, qemu

I am trying to load a simple kernel using the qemu emulator but, qemu gets stuck at "Booting from hard disk".
[image: A screenshot of the problem]

The source code for the kernel can be found in the following link: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-828-operating-system-engineering-fall-2012/ , in the lab 1 assignment in the directory `obj/kern/kernel.img`. [Pdf of lab1](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-828-operating-system-engineering-fall-2012/labs/MIT6_828F12_lab1.pdf), [tar.gz of lab1](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-828-operating-system-engineering-fall-2012/labs/lab1.tar.gz), [pointers1.c](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-828-operating-system-engineering-fall-2012/labs/pointers.c). The task was:

> The first part concentrates on getting familiarized with x86 assembly language, the
>   QEMU x86 emulator, and the PC's power-on bootstrap procedure. The second part examines the boot loader for our 6.828 kernel, which resides in the boot directory of the lab tree ...
>
> ```
>  % cd lab
>  % make
>  ...
>  + mk obj/kern/kernel.img
> ```
>
> .. Now you're ready to run QEMU, supplying the file obj/kern/kernel.img, created above, as the contents of the
>   emulated PC's "virtual hard disk." This hard disk image contains both our boot loader (obj/boot/boot) and our kernel
>   (obj/kernel).
>
> ```
>  % make qemu
> ```

Comment: add more information about the boot parameters what your providing. This pic doesn't help much to identify the problem your facing?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer Thanks for the response! I am using the following command: sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw, file=obj/kern/kernel.img

Comment: What is the `obj/kern/kernel.img`, is it bootable? What says `file -k obj/kern/kernel.img`?

Comment: @osgx Output from file -k obj/kern/kernel.img: DOS/MBR  boot sector DOS/MBR boot sector \012-data

Comment: eng140, post several kilobytes of it (as hexdump) here or on some pastebin/gist-like site (`dd if=obj/kern/kernel.img bs=512 count=20|hexdump -C`). How did you generate it or where it was downloaded? Why you think that qemu is stuck, will the code to be boot print something on text console?

Comment: @osgx I am following the OS Engineering course from MIT and I downloaded the files from their website for the lab1 assignment.  I think that qemu is stuck because after some time I get the following error: I/O thread spun for 1000 iterations.

Comment: We are not following the course, have no web links to its public website and have no access to internal assignment website. Add links to public part, post assignment task and  description, show the code. Add relevant information (error messages) to the question. Or the question may be closed as non-answerable.

Answer (score 2):

eng140,you could use a 32-bit Linux. I had the same problem. After having used a 32-bit Linux, this problem was solved. In the following web https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2017/tools.html
in the section "Using a virtual Machine", they recommend that we should use a 32-bit Linux.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of using a VM, if you are on a 64-bit Linux machine, you can create a compiler toolchain that generates 32-bit binaries by using `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib` (as explained in [the link](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2017/tools.html) shared in this answer).

Answer (score 2):

It also may be issue with gcc version. Latest available [Fall(2018)](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2014/jos.git) has fix for this

```
Author: Jonathan Behrens <fintelia@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 4 14:10:42 2018 -0400

Tweak kernel.ld linker script so edata and end are set correctly

This change should hopefully resolve issues when compiling with newer versions
of GCC.

commit a56269d4beefc7d0b3672180aa46c654cfb63af4
diff --git a/kern/kernel.ld b/kern/kernel.ld
index 45a0b6a..a219d1d 100644
--- a/kern/kernel.ld
+++ b/kern/kernel.ld
@@ -47,13 +47,13 @@ SECTIONS
                *(.data)
    }
-       PROVIDE(edata = .);
-
        .bss : {
+               PROVIDE(edata = .);
                *(.bss)
+               PROVIDE(end = .);
+               BYTE(0)
        }
-       PROVIDE(end = .);
        /DISCARD/ : {
                *(.eh_frame .note.GNU-stack)
```

Answer (score 1):

eng140, as explained in the course pdf MIT6_828F12_lab1.pdf - https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-828-operating-system-engineering-fall-2012/labs/MIT6_828F12_lab1.pdf, You should start qemu from the makefile with `make qemu`:

> This executes QEMU with the options required to set the hard disk and direct serial port output to the terminal. Some text should appear in the QEMU window: ...

You should not start it with manual procedure like you did (`qemu-system-x86_64 ..`). This target is implemented in lab GNUmakefile as

```
qemu: $(IMAGES) pre-qemu
    $(QEMU) $(QEMUOPTS)
```

and QEMU var is `qemu` on most platforms and i386-softmmu on MacOS. To, try to use 32-bit system version of qemu or standard `qemu` command. The options from makefile are like:

```
QEMUOPTS = -hda $(OBJDIR)/kern/kernel.img -serial mon:stdio -gdb tcp::$(GDBPORT)
QEMUOPTS += $(shell if $(QEMU) -nographic -help | grep -q '^-D '; then echo '-D qemu.log'; fi)
IMAGES = $(OBJDIR)/kern/kernel.img
QEMUOPTS += $(QEMUEXTRA)
```

The lab options have `-serial mon:stdio` which is ... http://download.qemu.org/qemu-doc.html

> `-serial dev`  -- 
>   Redirect the virtual serial port to host character device dev. .. This option can be used several times to simulate up to 4 serial ports. ...
>
> ```
> mon:dev_string
> ```
>
> This is a special option to allow the monitor to be multiplexed onto
>   another serial port. The monitor is accessed with key sequence of
>   Control-a and then pressing c. dev_string should be any one of the
>   serial devices specified above. An example to multiplex the monitor
>   onto a telnet server listening on port 4444 would be:

Probably your image to be boot uses serial port, not display to print things. Try adding to your command like:

```
qemu-system-i386 -drive format=raw,file=obj/kern/kernel.img -serial mon:stdio
```

or

```
qemu-system-i386 -hda obj/kern/kernel.img -serial mon:stdio
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried adding the above line to the GNUmakefile but it didn't work.

Comment: eng140, does `qemu-system-i386 -hda obj/kern/kernel.img -serial mon:stdio` line work? What is the text output of it?

Comment: It displays: Could not open qemu-system-i386, no such file or directory.

Comment: eng140, so do install it (or rebuild qemu)? You can't work with VM when you have only image of VM and not the virtual machine runner. I don't know how compatible are system-x86_64 and system-i386 in qemu.